# IBM Worklight 6.1.0 - Unable to deploy Worklight adapters using ANT tasks

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I've just updated my Worklight Studio from 6.0.0.1 to 6.1.0 and with the update I've gone ahead and updated the worklight-build-tools.jar on my path. It's worth mentioning that my team has already updated the project we're working on to 6.1.0.

Following the update, I ran the ANT tasks to build and deploy all project artifacts.
The result, I wasn't able to deploy the adapters to the local development server.

I unzipped the worklight-build-tools.jar and poked around for a while and found the adapter-deployer task has been moved to a different location within the jar. I added the new taskdef to my build.xml and got the error below.

Can someone shed some light on this? The class doesn't seem to exist in the jar at all.

Here is the error from the ant:

```
Buildfile: /Users/mario/Documents/workspace/workspace-myproject/MyWorklightProject/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/mario/Documents/workspace/workspace-myproject/MyWorklightProject/build.xml:35: taskdef class com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.UpdateAppServerTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[/Users/mario/Documents/workspace/workspace-myproject/MyWorklightProject/worklight-build-tools.jar]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `worklight-ant-builder.jar` and `worklight-ant-deployer.jar` after installing Worklight Server 6.1, and looking in the `WL_INSTALL_DIR/WorklightServer/` folder.

worklight-ant-builder.jar is for these tasks:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_apps.html

worklight-ant-deployer.jar is for these tasks:

- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_adapters.html
- http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_for_deploying_and_configuring.html

Comment: Hi Idan. Thanks for posting an answer. However, I see the documentation mentions 2 WL jar files. worklight-ant.jar and worklight-ant-deployer.jar but I only see 1 jar shipped with the product, worklight-build-tools.jar. The jar shipped contains the builder task definitions but not deployer task definitions. I feel like I'm missing something.