# Where is Worklight-Ant.jar?

Tags: ant, jar, ibm-mobilefirst

I've seen some documentation saying it was possible to use ant tasks to generate worklight builds.

That [documentation](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/Rational_Team_Concert_Integration.pdf) tells me that to use that feature I must find a worklight-ant.jar.

That is my problem, I don't find that jar anywhere. Not on my worklight studio installation nor in my (another) worklight server running on a WAS Liberty profile.

I've found on that server something close, I've found a worklight-ant-builder.jar and a worklight-ant-deployer.jar.
Unfortunately that doesn't have some classes required for the build, like com.ibm.team.build.ant.task.ArtifactFilePublisherTask.

Another good point was that I've found on my server the applicationcenterdeploytool.jar: from /ApplicationCenter/tools and the json4j.jar from /ApplicationCenter/tools.

I'm using WL6.2.

What am I missing? Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation I was using at the time of that post was out of date.

The updated documentation is here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_for_building_and_dep.html

On my comments there is a reference for a post that explains the correct way to call the ant to build the worklight.

Answer (score 1):

worklight-ant.jar is now delivered as part of the Worklight CLI installation.  Download the CLI here (Download button > CLI):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight

Once the CLI has been installed, you can find the worklight-ant-builder.jar file in the installation directory/public dir.  For example, in OSX, the default location is:

/Applications/IBM/Worklight-CLI/public/worklight-ant-builder.jar

Hope this helps.

Comment: Karl thanks for your answer, but please check my question in a greater detail. I've found that jar, but it doesn't have the classes the sample build.xml from the documentation I've linked refers. Is that sample that is out of date?

Comment: Oh btw, your link seems to be a internal link for the infocenter of IBM.

Comment: Sorry about the false link. I'll investigate why the current public docs differ from the internal one I was using, as there should be new information on the jar file delivered with CLI.

Comment: As far as that that Task you say is missing.  Are you getting an error?  What are you trying to do during the build cycle that you want to use that specific task.  I know some task names recently changed.

Comment: I've seen a answer by Idan Adar regarding this matter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931824/ibm-worklight-6-1-0-unable-to-deploy-worklight-adapters-using-ant-tasks). It looks like this is up to date. I'll investigate this issue further today because perhaps I was doing something wrong.